# dssp resulting in a FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, biopython

```html
S-adenosylmethionine synthase isoform type-1
('/Users/grb25/SS_HS/Q00266.pdb', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x000002A1ADE33D90>)
('/Users/grb25/SS_HS/Q00266.txt', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x000002A1ADE33BE0>)
Q00266
The 'try' is finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 31, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\grb25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\DSSP.py", line 385, in __init__
    version_string = subprocess.check_output(
  File "C:\Users\grb25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\grb25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\grb25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\grb25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

```
loc_pdb = "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".pdb"
loc_error = "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".txt"
struct = "https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/files/AF-{}-F1-model_v3.pdb".format(uniprot)
error = "https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/files/AF-{}-F1-model_v3.cif".format(uniprot)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(struct, loc_pdb)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(error, loc_error)
p = PDBParser()
structure = p.get_structure(uniprot, loc_pdb)
model = structure[0]
dssp = DSSP(model, "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".pdb", dssp='mkhssp')
```

I am trying to find the secondary structure of multiple proteins using dssp. I want to preface that I am a novice at Python so I don't know what I am doing really. I have a very long list of proteins that are being run so the **loc.pdb = "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".pdb"** should result in dssp opening the specific pdb file for the specific uniprot value. I get a **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified** however whenever I try to run the script. Any help is appreciated!

```
#For each unique protien accession number, go to the UniProt databse, and extract the protein's primary sequence
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser
from Bio.PDB.DSSP import DSSP
import urllib.request
index = 1
for uniprot in uniprots[1:]:    
    SS_list = []
    link = "https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/" + uniprot +".fasta"
    f = session.get(link)
    contents = f.text.splitlines()
    try:
        #print(index)
        #print(contents)
        SS_list.append(uniprot)
        protein_name = ' '.join(contents[0].split("|")[-1].split("OS")[0].split()[1:])
        print (index)
        protein_seq = "".join("".join(contents[1:]))
        totalAA = len(protein_seq)
        SS_list.append(protein_name)
        SS_list.append(totalAA)
        print(protein_name)
        helix_count = 0
        sheet_count = 0
        turn_count = 0
        unstructured_count = 0
        loc_pdb = "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".pdb"
        loc_error = "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".txt"
        struct = "https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/files/AF-{}-F1-model_v3.pdb".format(uniprot)
        error = "https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/files/AF-{}-F1-model_v3.cif".format(uniprot)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(struct, loc_pdb)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(error, loc_error)
        p = PDBParser()
        structure = p.get_structure(uniprot, loc_pdb)
        model = structure[0]
        dssp = DSSP(model, "/Users/grb25/SS_HS/" + uniprot + ".pdb", dssp='mkhssp')
        SS_list.append(len(dssp.keys()))
        for i in range(len(dssp.keys())):
            a_key = list(dssp.keys())[i]
            if dssp[a_key][2]== "G" or dssp[a_key][2]== "H" or dssp[a_key][2]== "I":
                helix_count += 1
            elif dssp[a_key][2]== "E" or dssp[a_key][2]== "B":
                sheet_count += 1
            elif dssp[a_key][2]== "S" or dssp[a_key][2]== "T":
                turn_count += 1
            elif dssp[a_key][2]== "-":
                unstructured_count += 1
```

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) print `uniprot` on the line before you try to load it, so you can be sure exactly what file your code is trying to load, (2) consider prefixing file paths with the drive letter (e.g. `C:`), so write `C:/Users/grb25/...` instead of `/Users/grb25/...`. Also, please edit the question to include the full traceback of the error, not just the message.

Comment: where does  f = session.get(link) : session came from ?? import missing

Comment: the import for the f = session.get(link) is at the beginning of the code, it's a large code so I didn't want to post all of it but I can if it would help.

Comment: figured out it's an issue with dssp no being installed correctly on my computer, so the error was in relation to the dssp not to my file I was trying to open.